# Merge an array into a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to take an array and merge it into an array of dictionaries but unsure as to how to do it.

I have an array of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
(
        {
        caption = a;
        urlRep = "12";
    },
        {
        caption = b;
        urlRep = "34";
    },
        {
        caption = c;
        urlRep = "56";
    }
)
```

and given an array like this:

```
(12,34,56,78)
```

I want to merge it into my dictionaries to make it look like this:

```
(
        {
        caption = a;
        urlRep = "12";
    },
        {
        caption = b;
        urlRep = "34";
    },
        {
        caption = c;
        urlRep = "56";
    },
        {
        caption = "";
        urlRep = "78";
    }
)
```

**edit:**
I need to also consider removing from the array of dicts if the given array does not contain one of the urlReps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck trying  to figure this out for some time.

Comment: "_I have a dictionary that looks like this_"... this actually is an array of dictionaries...

Comment: fixed to array of dicts, thanks

Comment: Hi BluGeni, Do you want to add array value in urlRep if its not available?

Comment: @sam'solution if you mean given a array like `(34,56)` I would like the new array to look like `({
        caption = b;
        urlRep = "34";
    },
        {
        caption = c;
        urlRep = "56";
    })`

Comment: Write software.  It's not that hard if you actually try.

Comment: @HotLicks If that were true, whats stackoverflow for?

Comment: Not for asking others to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple, efficient and elegant solution using `NSSet`s to handle unique keys:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfDicts;    // your input array of dictionaries
NSArray *urlRepArray;            // the new array with string elements

// create a set of potentially new keys (urlReps)
NSMutableSet *urlReps = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:urlRepArray];

// remove existing keys from your original array
[urlReps minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[arrayOfDicts valueForKey:@"urlRep"]]];

// merge new dicts to the original array
for (id urlRep in urlReps)
    [arrayOfDicts addObject:@{ @"urlRep" : urlRep, @"caption" : @"" }];
```

Comment: +1 better than mine, this should be the actual approach.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Is it also possible to remove an object from `arrayOfDicts` if it does not exist in `urlRepArray`

Comment: @BluGeni You should definitely make this clear in your question. "Merge" usually does not mean removing missing elements.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way AFAIK, Filter using `valueForKeyPath`

```
//Your array of dictionary I created here for debugging purpose.
NSArray *tmpArray = @[ @{@"caption":@"a",@"urlRep":@"12"},
                       @{@"caption":@"b",@"urlRep":@"34"},
                       @{@"caption":@"c",@"urlRep":@"56"}];

//This will give you 12,34,56 in your case
NSArray *existingURLRep = [tmpArray valueForKeyPath:@"urlRep"]; 

NSMutableArray *targetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@12, @34,@56, @78, nil]; //Assuming you have your array as you said
[targetArray removeObjectsInArray:existingURLRep];
//remove existing items  you will have 78 here now loop through 
//this targetArray and add it to your array of dictionary.
```

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com Thank you, still see nikolai's answer. Its proper approach.

Answer (score 1):

- (void)filterArray{

  NSLog(@"Array before filtering = %@",initialArray);
   NSLog(@"given Array = %@",givenArray);

  NSMutableSet *urlReps = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:givenArray];

  // remove existing records
  [urlReps minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[initialArray valueForKey:@"urlRep"]]];

  // adding new objects
  for (id obj in urlReps) {
          [initialArray addObject:@{@"caption":@"", @"urlRep" : obj}];
  }

  // removing objects
  NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

  for (id obj in initialArray) {
      NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = %@", dict[@"urlRep"]];
      NSArray *filteredArray = [givenArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
      if(filteredArray.count == 0) {
          [set addObject:dict];
      }
  }

  [initialArray removeObjectsInArray:[set allObjects]];

  NSLog(@"Array after filtering = %@",initialArray);
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray;//This will be your original array of dictionary.
NSArray *newArray;//This is your new array which you want to add.
for(id obj in newArray) {
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urlRep = %@", id];
NSArray *filteredArray = [locationsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if(filteredArray.count == 0) {
    [yourArray addObject:@{@"caption":@"", @"urlRep" : id}];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
NSArray *inputArray;//(12,34,56,78)- I assumes you are having array which contains strings. If you are having number then modify the code as you needed

NSMutableArray *colloectionArray;// your total collection

NSMutableArray *tobeMerged;
*/

// Extract the dictionary set only to be merged
for (NSString* aNumber in inputArray) {

    for (NSDictionary *aItem in colloectionArray) {

        NSString *urlRep= [aItem valueForKey:@"urlRep"];

        if (![urlRep isEqualToString:aNumber]) {
            [tobeMerged addObject:urlRep];
        }
    }

}

// Add missed items in collection
for (NSString *aNumber in tobeMerged) {

    NSMutableDictionary *newset = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [newset setObject:@"" forKey:@"caption"];
    [newset setObject:aNumber forKey:@"urlRep"];

    [colloectionArray addObject:newset];

}
```

Comment: Extracting can be done using `NSArray *existingURLRep = [tmpArray valueForKeyPath:@"urlRep"];`

Comment: we need the items that not in the existing collection

Comment: No offense, please See my answer. You can just achieve this in 3 lines.